# Can't open the main page XAML designer when open a new project

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, uwp

I'm just started using XAMl
so when i start a new project it shows this message in below

[image]

the only code was written is that

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
    compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: What happens when you reload the designer?

Comment: What is the relevance of the Winforms tag here?

Comment: @Steve. Noticed that too. It's mostly likely a UWP project.

Comment: @Steve i'm just a beginner in using XAML .. sorry for that

Comment: @bolkay when i reload it ... it shows the same message

Comment: The Designer child process is still buggy even though it was rewritten from WPF **XDesProc.exe** days .  Try rebooting your machine to know for sure

Comment: We could not figure out the issue with the screenshot. You may try to repair Visual Studio or check if you has installed the windows sdk.